# Why is the variable “curSpeed” in handlePositionUpdate(cObject* obj)equal to (-0,0,0)?

Tags: veins

When I run the examples in veins, I find the value of curSpeed is equal to (-0,0,0) always. Why?

```
void DemoBaseApplLayer::handlePositionUpdate(cObject* obj)
{
    ChannelMobilityPtrType const mobility = check_and_cast<ChannelMobilityPtrType>(obj);
    curPosition = mobility->getPositionAt(simTime());
    curSpeed = mobility->getCurrentSpeed();
    EV<<"DemoBaseApplLayer::handlePositionUpdate curSpeed="<<curSpeed<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because vehicle speed updates are disabled by default in the `TraCIMobility` module (see **setHostSpeed** param in the [TraCIMobility.ned file](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/bb22b2739db75b0f8280a95e874fb2dee4f4ac54/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.ned#L48)). It is also disabled by default in the `omnetpp.ini` configuration file of the Veins example scenario.

To enable vehicle speed updates, make sure that `setHostSpeed` parameter is set to `true` in the `omnetpp.ini` config:

```
*.node[*].veinsmobility.setHostSpeed = true
```

This applies to the default Veins example when using the default TraCIMobility module. Tested on Instant Veins 5.2-i1.